# ExifInterface.getDateTime and getGpsDateTime is not exist

Tags: java, android, metadata, exif

So i was diving through ExifInterface class for android. You can see it here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/ExifInterface.java

There are methods called getDateTime() and getGpsDateTime(). I wonder why i can't access these methods directly from my project, since it has public access modifier, while i can access other methods like getAltitude(double defaultValue), getAttribute(String tag), etc.

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html also no documentation about getDateTime() and getGpsDateTime()

I already searched about this issue but no luck. Did i missed something? Please don't answer about alternatives to get date time or gps date time, since i already know how to do that, i just curious about the concept here.

Comment: because    `@hide`

Comment: why do they need to hide them?

Comment: Ask 'em ... such methods are not a part of public API ... you can try to use it via Reflection but there is no guarantee that such methods are implemented on all devices